# Page Photo Tagged?

Tags: facebook, tagging

I need to catch ALL the images in which a page is tagged? Which is the method? Using the /page-id/tagged I was not able to do that. Is there some specific permission that needs to be set? Is there any example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest trying to query the photo_tag table using the page id.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/

Here's some FQL that works well for me:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20pid%2C%20text%2C%20subject%20FROM%20photo_tag%20WHERE%20subject%20in%20(SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_admin%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme())

`SELECT pid, text, subject FROM photo_tag WHERE subject in (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid=me())`

Comment: Thanks. Does it works also for public pages I'm not admin of them?

Comment: Thanks, what if i need to access the info through a server app without the FB user login? How can I do?

Comment: Sorry, you cannot do that.  You must have a mechanism to allow the user to grant you app permissions.